# DotNet CsvHelper RFC4180 Mode Escape Double Quote

Tags: .net, csv, csvhelper

I am parsing a file that contains the following data as part of a line.

```
12.0000¦6.11000¦LB¦9189AD510001¦Photo Insert 5\" x 5\"Iron¦¦¦23.00¦13.50¦5.00¦IN¦1726.31250¦
```

I have the following config on my parser

```
var parserConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = fileMap.Delimiter,
        HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader,
        Mode = CsvMode.RFC4180,
        Escape = EscapeCharacter
    };
```

Where delimiter is broken pipe (¦) and Escape character is backslash ('\'). When I parse the data is stops parsing at the field containing `9189AD510001` and acts like everything after does not exist.

How do I escape the double quote so that the file will parse properly? I have also tried to escape the double quote with another double quote thus having ("").

I need to use RFC4180 mode as I also parse files that contain fields wrapped in quotes `5,6,52,in,1560,"cubic in",10,lb`.

EDIT: Sample [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdvwPI)
We are reading multiple file structures and doing all the mapping dynamically.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the model + class map + CSV headers (if `hasHeader == true`) that you are using?  I started one here https://dotnetfiddle.net/b5PFbU but I don't know what to put for the properties of the model.

Comment: The sample CSV file was written using `Mode = CsvMode.Escape` and can be parsed using the same mode, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/0KO38Q.  Why do you insist on using RFC4180 mode?  You already have `fileMap` with properties `Delimiter` and `EscapeCharacter`, why not add in `Mode` as well?  Alternatively, can your CSV file's format be modified to be consistent with RFC4180?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do it would be to also dynamically pass the `CsvMode` to your `CsvConfiguration`. `CsvMode.Escape` was specifically created to handle the example you gave where the double quotes are escaped with a backslash (or any other designated escape character) and the field is not contained in double quotes, per RFC 4180. Unfortunately, there is no way to get `CsvMode.RFC4180` to properly handle that.

If you know the file with the broken pipe delimiter (¦) is always going to be formatted that way, you could switch on `fileMap.Delimiter`.

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = fileMap.Delimiter,
    HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader,
    Mode = fileMap.Delimiter == "¦" ? CsvMode.Escape : CsvMode.RFC4180,
    Escape = EscapeCharacter
};
```